# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka application not generating messages with the correct Avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have an application (spring-boot-shipping-service) with a KStream that gets OrderCreatedEvent messages generated by an external producer (spring-boot-order-service). This producer uses the following schema:

**order-created-event.avsc**

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.codependent.statetransfer.order",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "OrderCreatedEvent",
  "fields" : [
    {"name":"id","type":"int"},
    {"name":"productId","type":"int"},
    {"name":"customerId","type":"int"}
  ]
}
```

My `KStream<Int, OrderCreatedEvent>` is joined with a `KTable<Int, Customer>` and publishes to the order topic a new kind of message: OrderShippedEvent.

order-shipped-event.avsc

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.codependent.statetransfer.order",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "OrderShippedEvent",
  "fields" : [
    {"name":"id","type":"int"},
    {"name":"productId","type":"int"},
    {"name":"customerName","type":"string"},
    {"name":"customerAddress","type":"string"}
  ]
}
```

For some reason the new OrderShippedEvent messages aren't generated with a header `application/vnd.ordershippedevent.v1+avro` but `application/vnd.ordercreatedevent.v1+avro`.

This is the original OrderCreatedEvent in the order topic:

```
Key (4 bytes): +
  Value (4 bytes): V?
  Timestamp: 1555943926163
  Partition: 0
  Offset: 34
  Headers: contentType="application/vnd.ordercreatedevent.v1+avro",spring_json_header_types={"contentType":"java.lang.String"}
```

And the produced OrderShippedEvent with the incorrect schema:

```
Key (4 bytes): +
  Value (26 bytes): V?
JamesHill Street
  Timestamp: 1555943926163
  Partition: 0
  Offset: 35
  Headers: contentType="application/vnd.ordercreatedevent.v1+avro",spring_json_header_types={"contentType":"java.lang.String"}
```

I've checked the Confluent Schema Registry contents, and the order-shipped-event.avsc schema is there:

[image]

Why isn't it using the correct shema in the generated message?

Below you can see the full configuration and code of the example, which is also available on Github (https://github.com/codependent/event-carried-state-transfer/tree/avro)

In order to test it just start a Confluent Platform (v5.2.1), spring-boot-customer-service, spring-boot-order-service, spring-boot-shipping-service and execute the following curl commands:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/customers -d '{"id":1,"name":"James","address":"Hill Street"}' -H "content-type: application/json"`

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8084/orders -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"id":1,"productId":1001,"/customerId":1}'`

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8085

spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-shipping-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: customer
          contentType: application/*+avro
        order:
          destination: order
          contentType: application/*+avro
        output:
          destination: order
          contentType: application/*+avro
      schema-registry-client:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
```

**ShippingKStreamProcessor**

```
interface ShippingKStreamProcessor {

    @Input("input")
    fun input(): KStream<Int, Customer>

    @Input("order")
    fun order(): KStream<String, OrderCreatedEvent>

    @Output("output")
    fun output(): KStream<String, OrderShippedEvent>
```

**ShippingKStreamConfiguration**

```
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<Int, Customer>, @Input("order") orderEvent: KStream<Int, OrderCreatedEvent>): KStream<Int, OrderShippedEvent> {

        val serdeConfig = mapOf(
                AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG to "http://localhost:8081")

        val intSerde = Serdes.IntegerSerde()
        val customerSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<Customer>()
        customerSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true)
        val orderCreatedSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<OrderCreatedEvent>()
        orderCreatedSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true)
        val orderShippedSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<OrderShippedEvent>()
        orderShippedSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true)


        val stateStore: Materialized<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>> =
                Materialized.`as`<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("customer-store")
                        .withKeySerde(intSerde)
                        .withValueSerde(customerSerde)

        val customerTable: KTable<Int, Customer> = input.groupByKey(Serialized.with(intSerde, customerSerde))
                .reduce({ _, y -> y }, stateStore)

        return (orderEvent.filter { _, value -> value is OrderCreatedEvent && value.id != 0 }
                .selectKey { _, value -> value.customerId } as KStream<Int, OrderCreatedEvent>)
                .join(customerTable, { orderIt, customer ->
                    OrderShippedEvent(orderIt.id, orderIt.productId, customer.name, customer.address)
                }, Joined.with(intSerde, orderCreatedSerde, customerSerde))
                .selectKey { _, value -> value.id }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I've set trace logging level for org.springframework.messaging and apparently it looks ok:

```
2019-04-22 23:40:39.953 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/ordercreatedevent/versions/1
2019-04-22 23:40:39.971 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2019-04-22 23:40:39.972 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [] as "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"
2019-04-22 23:40:39.984 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2019-04-22 23:40:39.985 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.util.Map<?, ?>]
2019-04-22 23:40:40.186  INFO 46039 --- [read-1-producer] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: 5Sw6sBD0TFOaximF3Or-dQ
2019-04-22 23:40:40.318 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter : Obtaining schema for class class com.codependent.statetransfer.order.OrderShippedEvent
2019-04-22 23:40:40.318 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter : Avro type detected, using schema from object
2019-04-22 23:40:40.342 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/ordershippedevent/versions
2019-04-22 23:40:40.342 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2019-04-22 23:40:40.342 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"OrderShippedEvent\",\"namespace\":\"com.codependent.statetransfer.order\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"productId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"customerName\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},{\"name\":\"customerAddress\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}}]}"}] as "application/json"
2019-04-22 23:40:40.348 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2019-04-22 23:40:40.348 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.util.Map<?, ?>]
2019-04-22 23:40:40.349 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/ordershippedevent
2019-04-22 23:40:40.349 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2019-04-22 23:40:40.349 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"OrderShippedEvent\",\"namespace\":\"com.codependent.statetransfer.order\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"productId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"customerName\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},{\"name\":\"customerAddress\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}}]}"}] as "application/json"
2019-04-22 23:40:40.361 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2019-04-22 23:40:40.362 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.util.Map<?, ?>]
2019-04-22 23:40:40.362 DEBUG 46039 --- [-StreamThread-1] AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter : Finding correct DatumWriter for type com.codependent.statetransfer.order.OrderShippedEvent
```

How come the message is written with an incorrect content type header then?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've kept digging into the source code and found this:

1. `KafkaStreamsMessageConversionDelegate` correctly converts and determines the right header values, as seen in the logs above.
2. **However** in the serializeOnOutbound method we can find that it returns to the Kafka API only the payload, so **the headers aren't taken into account**:

```
return
                    messageConverter.toMessage(message.getPayload(),
                            messageHeaders).getPayload();
```

3. Moving forward in the record processing `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process()` accesses the headers present in the context, which incorrectly contain `application/vnd.ordercreatedevent.v1+avro` instead of `application/vnd.ordershippedevent.v1+avro` (?):

```
collector.send(topic, key, value, context.headers(), timestamp, keySerializer, valSerializer, partitioner);
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download and start Confluent 5.2.1
   `confluent start`
2. Start the applications spring-boot-order-service, spring-boot-customer-service, spring-boot-shipping-service
3. Create a customer `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/customers -d '{"id":1,"name":"John","address":"Some Street"}' -H "content-type: application/json"`
4. Create an order that will be joined with the customer: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8084/orders -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"id":1,"productId":1,"customerId":1}'`
5. ShippingKStreamConfiguration's `process()` will create a KTable for the Customer and a state store (customer-store). Besides, it will join the order stream with the customer KTable to transform an OrderCreatedEvent into an OrderShippedEvent.
6. You can check that the newly created OrderShippedEvent message added to the order topic has an incorrect header. This can be seen either in the Confluent Control Center (`localhost:9092 -> topics -> order`) or running kafkacat:

```
$> kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t order -C \
  -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k   
  Value (%S bytes): %s
  Timestamp: %T
  Partition: %p
  Offset: %o
  Headers: %h\n'
```

Comment: Looks like you are making a lot of progress in resolving this issue. I can take a look at this tomorrow and get back to you. In the meantime, if you find any more info, please update here.

Comment: I don't see `spring-boot-order-service` in the repository. I am trying to reproduce the issue. Could you include the exact steps to run your system and see the issue?

Comment: The project is in the avro branch of the repo: https://github.com/codependent/event-carried-state-transfer/tree/avro -> https://github.com/codependent/event-carried-state-transfer/tree/avro/spring-boot-order-service

Comment: Updated with steps to reproduce. Thanks for having a look at it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@codependent It is indeed an issue that we need to address in the binder which we will fix soon. In the meantime, as a workaround can you make your processor not return a `KStream`, but rather do the sending in the method itself. You can call `to(TopicNameExtractor)` on the currently returned `KStream`. `TopicNameExtractor` will give you access to the record context using which you can manually set the content type.

Comment: Here's the link to the issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/456